# MYSLI_QUERY return false but MYSQLI_ERROR not displaying error after updating php 7.2 from 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, php-7.2

After updating to PHP 7.2 mysqli_query() returns false but not displaying error when I use mysqli_error()

I changed the functions to the updated versions.
Mysqli_query function or Mysqli_error seems not working proper or not error but It does not display the database content and mysqli_query return false.

```
<?php
$conex=mysqli_connect('dburl','dbuser','dbpass', 'dbname');
if ($conex == false) {
    echo mysqli_errno().': '.mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `opiniones`";
$resul2 = mysqli_query($query2, $conex);
if ($resul2 == false) {
    echo "Error:<br>".mysqli_errno($conex).': '.mysqli_error($conex)."<br />";
    echo "Not entering opiniones.<br />";
}
while ($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resul2)) {
    echo $fila2['autor'];
}
mysqli_free_result($resul2);
?>
```

Comment: Change the first `mysqli_error` to `mysqli_connect_error`, and don't check for false.

Comment: The problem persist. Nothing changes.

Comment: Update the question with your code now.

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled. [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/1839439)

Comment: I hope those aren't real database credentials you've included there.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you do not check if the connection was successful. To check the connection error you can use [`mysqli_connect_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)

Your second issue is that you have the reverse order of arguments passed to [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
It should be:

```
$resul2 = mysqli_query($conex, $query2);
```

You should also consider [switching MySQLi exception mode on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments/22662582#22662582)

Comment: Solved!
That was the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How come you were not receiving any errors from PHP? Are you sure that you have error_reporting switched on?

Comment: After updating php versión might be disabled, but it is uploaded through a hosting company and It seems don't have access to php.ini file.